# "script/server" Error in RoR RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I am running a RoR application using RVM, after an upgrade from the author. It prompted me to install a later version of ruby: ruby-1.9.3-p448 instead of ruby-1.8.7-p374, which I have installed it using RVM.

Now when I run `script/server` it throws this error:

```
/home/abcsoeasy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:3:in '<top (required)>': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.18 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
/home/abcsoeasy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21:in 'add_frozen_gem_path': undefined method 'source_index' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /home/abcsoeasy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/initializer.rb:298:in 'add_gem_load_paths'
    from /home/abcsoeasy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/initializer.rb:132:in 'process'
    from /home/abcsoeasy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/initializer.rb:113:in 'run'
    from /home/abcsoeasy/epz_lts-master/config/environment.rb:7:in '<top (required)>'
    from /home/abcsoeasy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in 'require'
    from /home/abcsoeasy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in 'block in require'
    from /home/abcsoeasy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in 'new_constants_in'
    from /home/abcsoeasy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in 'require'
    from /home/abcsoeasy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/commands/server.rb:84:in '<top (required)>'
    from script/server:3:in 'require'
    from script/server:3:in '<main>'
```

Please guide me.

Comment: try running this command: `gem update --system 1.8.25`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your gem version causing this issue. You need to downgrade gem version to `1.8.2x` will fix this issue. Or you can also downgrade your ruby version. Try using `ruby 1.9.3-p327`it's working great on my local. Hope this help you.

Comment: I think the issue is with the gem version, not the ruby. Will check to it

Comment: Yes it's problem with gem version and I think `ruby 1.9.3-p327` uses `1.8.27`.

Comment: thanks a lot, crossed over that error. by running `rvm rubygems 1.8.27 --force`